# Django ModeuleNotFoundError:

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project all set up, several apps that work fine but I have a folder with a few python files in it and on top of each file I have:

```py
    import os
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'My Project.settings')
    import django
    django.setup()
```

If I take the file out of the folder then it works fine but if I try to run in while it is in the folder I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyProject'

The setup looks like this:

```py
    MyProject
        MyProject
            settings.py
        More Apps
        Folder
            .py file that wont work in folder
```

Is there something I need to edit in my import above to get the files to work while in the folder?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you want to execute arbitrary Python code, make it a custom management command. It's much easier than trying to init the Django environment yourself like you did above.